# Error creating bean with name 'conversionService'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I don't understand, why class CategoryFormatter.java not found.  (IntellijIdea + Tomcat 9 + Maven)

**mvc-core.config**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>    
      <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
            <property name="formatters">
                <set>
                    <bean class="diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter"/>
                </set>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

**WhatsNewService.java**

```
package diplom.whatsnew.server.service;

import diplom.whatsnew.server.model.*;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import java.util.Collection;



public interface WhatsNewService {

    Collection<Category> findCategory() throws DataAccessException;

    City findCityById(int id) throws DataAccessException;

    Places findPlaceById(int id) throws DataAccessException;

    void savePlace(Places place) throws DataAccessException;

    void deletePlace(Places place) throws DataAccessException;

    void saveEvents(Events events) throws DataAccessException;

    void deleteEvente(Events events) throws DataAccessException;

    void saveCity(City city) throws DataAccessException;

    Collection<Users> findUsers() throws  DataAccessException;

    Collection<City> findCityByName(String name) throws  DataAccessException;
}
```

**CategoryFormatter.java**

```
package diplom.whatsnew.server.web;
import diplom.whatsnew.server.model.Category;
import diplom.whatsnew.server.service.WhatsNewService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.Formatter;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Locale;
public class CategoryFormatter implements Formatter<Category> {

private final WhatsNewService whatsNewService;

@Autowired
public CategoryFormatter(WhatsNewService whatsNewService)
{
    this.whatsNewService=whatsNewService;
}

@Override
public String print(Category category, Locale locale)
{
    return  category.getName();
}

@Override
public Category parse(String text,Locale locale) throws ParseException{
    Collection<Category> findCategory=this.whatsNewService.findCategory();
    for(Category category: findCategory){
        if(category.getName().equals(text)){
            return category;
        }
    }
    throw new ParseException("type not found: " + text, 0);
}

}
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

<display-name>Spring WhatsNew</display-name>
<description>Spring WhatsNew sample application</description>


<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml, classpath:spring/tools-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>whatsnew</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-core-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>whatsnew</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dandelion-assets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**error**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in class path
>   resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean
>   'diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter#19b8e7d5' of type
>   [diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter] while setting bean
>   property 'formatters' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter] for bean
>   with name 'diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter#19b8e7d5'
>   defined in class path resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter] for bean
>   with name 'diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter#77b6dc78'
>   defined in class path resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]; nested
>   exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter

Comment: How do you package your app and run it? Is the class on the runtime classpath?

Comment: What is CategoryFormmater? Do you have any spring annotations on it, they cannot be seen. Also paste it's package name which you see on top.

Comment: why do you want to use `prototype` scoped bean (inner bean)? where is `WhatsNewService` bean defined that is used to instantiate `CategoryFormatter` bean in constructor?

Comment: @Nadir I'm using Apache Tomcat 9

Comment: @WeareBorg It' a class

Comment: I got that its a class, that was not the point, shouldn't you annotate your class with `@Component` or `@Service` if you want Spring to work with it?

Comment: @WeareBorg I annotated this like Component  before, but the error was the same

Comment: `</web-app>` is commented out, just saying.

Comment: Ok, how does your app look after packaging and before deployment? Did you check that your CategoryFormatter class is there where it's supposed to be? Also are your spring libs insde your app or in some shared lib folder ? I could imagine a scenario where spring classes are loaded from shared place, and because of that they cannot see your classes (I'm not a tomcat 9 specialist, but I have seen similar case in some JBoss release)

Comment: @Nadir I've checked all lib and classes, they are in order

Comment: @cihanseven beacuse stack editor recognize this <url-pattern>/dandelion-assets/*</url-pattern> like comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this problem with rebuilding maven project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here for bean definition Spring awaits no-arg constructor:

```
<bean class="diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter"/>
```

and in your class you have one with autowired argument

```
@Autowired
public CategoryFormatter(WhatsNewService whatsNewService)
{
    this.whatsNewService=whatsNewService;
}
```

so bean is not created

To fix change in xml declaration (mvc-core-config.xml)

```
<bean class="diplom.whatsnew.server.web.CategoryFormatter">
      <constructor-arg ref="whatsNewService"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess here is the Problem.

I took a look at your project.

I think the name of the class is PlaceCategoryFormatter and not CategoryFormatter under package **diplom.whatsnew.server.web**

Please double check .